# Module css not displayed

Tags: blocks

I have created a custom module for Drupal 7 that displays a block, and I would like to add some CSS. The problem is that the CSS is not working.

This is the module code.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 */
function filter_search_form_block_info() {
  $blocks['filter_search_form'] = array(
    'info' => t('Filter Search Form'),
    // 'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE,
  );

  return $blocks;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 */
function filter_search_form_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();

  switch ($delta) {
    case 'filter_search_form':
      $block['subject'] = t('block Title');
      $block['content'] = array(
        '#markup' => '<div id="filter-search-form">
          <form id="filter-search-form-form">           
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-text" name="txt_search">
                <label for="chk_brigadista">' . t('Brigadista') . '</label>
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="chk_brigadista">
                <label for="chk_fuente">' . t('Fuente Documental') . '</label>
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="chk_fuente">
                <label for="chk_encuadramiento">' . t('Encuadramiento Militar') . '</label>
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="chk_encuadramiento">
                <input type="submit" value="' . t('search') . '">
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>',
          '#attached' => array(
            'css' => array(
              drupal_get_path('module', 'filter_search_form') . '/css'
             ),
             'js' => array(
               drupal_get_path('module', 'filter_search_form') . '/js/'
             ),
           ),
         );
         break;
    }

    return $block;
}
```

This is the module .info file.

```
name = Filter Search Form
description = Module that create a Block for Filter Search Form, form with checboxes to filter search.
core = 7.x
package = CUSTOM

scripts[] = 'js/filter_search_form.js'

stylesheets[all][] = css/filter_search_form.css
```

These are the CSS styles.

```
#filter-search-form {
    float:left;
    background-color:red;
}
```

Why aren't the CSS styles applied to the module output? I cleared the cache with `drush cc all`.

The structure is:

- css/

  - filter_search_form.css
- js/

  - filter_search_form.js
- filter_search_form.info
- filter_search_form.module

Comment: File(s) arent specified.

Comment: To clarify the comment above you need to attach each CSS file individually, you can't attach the containing folder.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to rename the CSS file.

> The word "style" can not be used in the name, like "myown_style.css".
>   It will conflict with the default style.css. Anyhow, myownstyle.css
>   will work.

See [Adding style sheets from .info files](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/working-with-css/adding-style-sheets-from-info-files) for more details.

Comment: I have renamed the file, updated the .info and I have updated the question. But it doesn't work. I will put the css in the theme if there is not a way to do it.

Comment: If it doesn't work there must be something else preventing the CSS from being included (other modules, theme config, etc). You could always use `drupal_add_css()` as a workaround.